# Can I override callback url with sub-domain for Xero OAuth2 authentication

Tags: xero-api

I have a Rails App that accesses Xero using new OAuth2 authentication, where we use a sub-domain to isolate different organisations. eg https://domain.example.com

To date we have to create a new Xero App for each domain, as we have to specify the callback url for the app, which in the case above would be https://domain.example.com/auth/xero_oauth/callback

Is it possible to register a single App with Xero with a callback URL of https://example.com/auth/xero_oauth/callback and to then override the URL, adding the sub-domain, for the Connection phase.

I'm fairly certain I could do this with the previous OAuth1 version.

Answer (score 1):

I also have this requirement, but its not the first time I've bumped up against this issue with OAuth applications.

I work around it by adding the subdomain to the `state` parameter that's passed in to the initial authorization step, and passed back to the redirect URI:

```
$state = json_encode(['uuid' => $uuid, 'subdomain' => $subdomain]);
```

Then in my redirect URI I extract the subdomain from the state, and perform another redirect to that subdomain along with the UUID (to perform CSRF check).

<del>The downside with this approach is the state is only passed back on success; if the OAuth flow encounters an error, your redirect URI won't be able to determine the correct subdomain.</del>

**EDIT**: Turns out Xero does return the state regardless of success or failure :)

Comment: You mind sharing your callback method where you check the UUID?

Comment: @rept You generate the UUID on `{subdomain}.yourapp.com`, and store it in the user's session before encoding it as above and beginning the OAuth flow. Once the user authorizes, they arrive back to `yourapp.com/callback?state={encoded_state}` where you can decode the UUID and subdomain from the state. Lastly, you do a further redirect to `{subdomain}.yourapp.com/callback?uuid={uuid}` where you can compare the provided parameter against the value in the session.

Answer (score 0):

thats an interesting use case. Pretty sure we don't allow wildcard subdomains in the callback urls, and the limit is 3 per app. But I will check next week! Have you created a ticket with api@xero.com? Also if you open an issue on the Ruby SDK I can try and sort this for you soon.

Thinking through this out loud.. might be possible to step in front of the callback url.. though probably would cause issue with the Xero client generation as it needs to match the OAuth2.0 settings in /myapps..  Could you redirect back to your root domain just for auth, then kick them to their subdomain post success?

Comment: Silly question, where do you log a ticket? It's not immediately evident. I did log a question in Developer Community .. https://community.xero.com/developer/discussion/111143907/   As to being able to handle the callback from the root domain, the subdomains run as separate instances, so there isn't a root instance, the selling point to our clients is that there is complete separation of data.

Comment: Please email api@xero.com - a member of our API tech support will be in contact.

Comment: @serKnight, I have multiple business in my system. so when new Business registered in my system then that business also have to create xero account and organization to use my system? Can you please help me this stuff!